# Prevent clock from advancing to a system time after Ubuntu Server build time

Tags: server, time, date, clock, rtc

I have an Ubuntu Server 18.04.1 LTS in a lab environment where I need to set the date a couple of years back in time (e.g. 2016-04-22). I can set the older date/time without any issues but the OS always resets the date/time to 2018-01-28 15:58 whenever I power the server back on. **How can I prevent this?**

I found a log message in /var/log/syslog indicating that the OS is switching to the previous build time: *systemd[1]: System time before build time, advancing clock.*

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the `systemd-timesyncd` service:

```
sudo systemctl disable systemd-timesyncd
```

You can check if the service is running using:

```
sudo service systemd-timesyncd status
```

You can stop the service manually (one time) using:

```
sudo service systemd-timesyncd stop
```

Comment: Sadly, the Local and Universal times still get reset to the build time when I reboot. I made your suggested changes then entered:  
`sudo timedatectl set-time "2007-08-10 02:00:00"`
After the reboot the time was:
`$ timedatectl
                     Local time: Sun 2018-01-28 15:59:06 UTC
                 Universal time: Sun 2018-01-28 15:59:06 UTC
                       RTC time: Fri 2007-08-10 02:01:25
                      Time zone: UTC (UTC, +0000)
      System clock synchronized: no
system-timesyncd.service active: no
                RTC in local TZ: no`